# PHP непечатаемый символ

Tags: php

```
    $users = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('users.csv'));
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $user = explode(';', $user);
        var_dump($user); 
    }
```

При получении строки с `users.csv` и последующем ее `explode` по `;` получаю длину `1` элемента массива на 1 больше, чем нужно.

Ощущение, что это `PHP_EOL`, но убрать я его не могу.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "icyftl"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "alpine"
}
```

Не знаю что делать.

Comment: что-то я не понял куда тут смотреть.

Comment: @teran, убрал лишнее

Comment: если в вашем файле содержится единственная строка `icyftl;alpine` то вы получаете то что и должно быть. В противном случае приведите входные данные, и таки опишите что хотите получить.